# How to get float values in range without using numpy?

Tags: python

I have two endpoints as following, to which I want the expected result as a list. Can someone please help to achieve this without using numpy in Python.

```
Start: 15
End: 27.5
Expected Result: 15,15.5....27,27.5
```

Comment: Try writing a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def frange(start, stop, step):
    while start <= stop:
        yield start
        start += step

>>> list(frange(15, 27.5, 0.5))
[15, 15.5, 16.0, 16.5, 17.0, 17.5, 18.0, 18.5, 19.0, 19.5, 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5, 22.0, 22.5, 23.0, 23.5, 24.0, 24.5, 25.0, 25.5, 26.0, 26.5, 27.0, 27.5]
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for.